# NSPrintOperation context is always nil, causing a crash. How do I set the context when printing?

Tags: macos, printing, nsprintoperation

I have a custom NSView that I want to print. After setting things up with the NSView and the print options, I make this call:

```
NSPrintOperation *printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView: printView printInfo: printInfo];

[NSPrintOperation setCurrentOperation: printOperation];
[printView beginDocument];

NSGraphicsContext* theContext = printOperation.context;
```

"theContext" is always nil. If I ignore that, when I make this call:

```
[printView beginPageInRect: rect atPlacement: location];
```

I get an exception, saying: "[General] lockFocus/unlockFocus sent to a view which is not in a window"

If I comment that out, I get about a billion messages that say this: "CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable." Turning on the backtrace just shows all of my drawing is what is causing it.

If I look at the graphics context within my view's "DrawRect:" function:

```
NSGraphicsContext *graphicsContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
CGContextRef      context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
```

both graphicsContext and context are nil.

So, what do I have to do to get a valid printing context? I see that there is a NSPrintOperation method createContext, but the docs say not to call it directly, and if I ignore that, it doesn't help and shoots about eight empty jobs to the printer.

Latest version of code, which still results in a null context:

```
NSPrintOperation *printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView: printView printInfo: printInfo];

[printView setCurrentForm: [formSet objectAtIndex: 0]];

NSInteger pageCounter = 0;
formHeight = 0;
formWidth = 0;

for (AFVForm *oneForm in formSet)
{
    printView.verticalOffset = formHeight;
    NSRect  rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, oneForm.pageWidth, oneForm.pageHeight);
    NSPoint location = [printView locationOfPrintRect: rect];

    formHeight += [oneForm pageHeight];
    if ([oneForm pageWidth] > formWidth)
        formWidth = [oneForm pageWidth];
    pageCounter++;
    printView.currentForm = oneForm;
    [printView setPrintMode: YES];

    [printView drawRect: NSZeroRect];

    [printView setPrintMode: NO];
}

[printOperation setShowsPrintPanel:YES];
[printOperation runOperationModalForWindow: [self window] delegate: nil didRunSelector: nil contextInfo: nil];
```

Comment: Figured it out -- the views get drawn during "runOperationModalForWindow:" with the context properly set, meaning that the whole "for (AFVForm *oneForm in formSet)" section was unnecessary and was what was causing all the errors. Taking that out resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`beginDocument` and `beginPageInRect:atPlacement:` are called at the beginning of the printing session and at the beginning of each page. Override these methods if you want but don't call them. Don't call `setCurrentOperation`, just create a `NSPrintOperation` and call `runOperation` or `runOperationModalForWindow:delegate:didRunSelector:contextInfo:`.

See [Printing Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_aboutprinting/osxp_aboutprt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000083-SW1)

Edit, example:

PrintView.h

```
@interface PrintView : NSView

@property (strong) NSArray *forms;

@end
```

PrintView.m

```
@interface PrintView ()

@property (weak) NSTextField *titleField;
@property (weak) NSDictionary *currentForm;

@end


@implementation PrintView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect]) {
        // add a title text field
        NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(25.0, 225.0, 250.0, 25.0)];
        textField.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [self addSubview:textField];
        self.titleField = textField;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)knowsPageRange:(NSRangePointer)range {
    range->location = 1;
    range->length = self.forms.count;
    return YES;
}

- (NSRect)rectForPage:(NSInteger)page {
    return self.bounds;
}

- (void)beginPageInRect:(NSRect)rect atPlacement:(NSPoint)location {
    [super beginPageInRect:rect atPlacement:location];
    NSPrintOperation *printOperation = [NSPrintOperation currentOperation];
    self.currentForm = self.forms[printOperation.currentPage - 1];
    // set the title
    [self.titleField setStringValue:
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Form ‘%@’ page %li",
            self.currentForm[@"title"], (long)printOperation.currentPage]];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    // Drawing code here.
    // draw a colored frame
    NSColor *formColor = self.currentForm[@"color"];
    NSRect rect = self.bounds;
    NSInsetRect(rect, 20.0, 20.0);
    [formColor set];
    NSFrameRect(rect);
}

@end
```

somewhere else

```
- (IBAction)printAction:(id)sender {
    PrintView *printView = [[PrintView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 300.0)];
    printView.forms = @[
            @{@"title":@"Form A", @"color":[NSColor redColor]},
            @{@"title":@"Form B", @"color":[NSColor greenColor]},
            @{@"title":@"Form C", @"color":[NSColor blueColor]},
        ];
    NSPrintOperation *printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:printView];
    [printOperation setShowsPrintPanel:YES];
    [printOperation runOperationModalForWindow:[self window] delegate:nil didRunSelector:NULL contextInfo:NULL];
}
```

Comment: I've read the Programming Guide over and over and can't find anything that explains why the context is nil. I've changed the code to reflect your suggestions, same thing -- the context is nil, and I get a bunch of "CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable." because of the null context.

Comment: @DaleJensen Did you remove `[printView beginDocument];` and `[printView beginPageInRect: rect atPlacement: location];`? Please post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question.

Answer (score -1):

A Swift example, goes in your NSView subclass. I apologize if it isn't helpful:

```
         func letsPrint() {
             let pInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared
             let d = pInfo.dictionary()
             d["NSLastPage"] = 1
             super.printView(self)
         }
         override func knowsPageRange(_ range: NSRangePointer) -> Bool {
             return true
         }
         override func rectForPage(_ page: Int) -> NSRect {
             if page > 1 { return NSZeroRect }
             return NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 612, height: 792)
         }
```

This example prints 1 page, 8.5 x 11, hence the constants in rectForPage

letsPrint is wired to the app menu first responder.

Comment: Not a great example. `knowsPageRange` returns `true`, what is `range`? Better use `NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey.lastPage` instead of `"NSLastPage"`. Why do you set `d["NSLastPage"]`? `super.printView` instead of `self.printView`? The preview shows an active > button.